# My pronunciation of "ul" in pull, culture, multiple - a mid back rounded vowel?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I've puzzled over my pronunciation of "ul" in words like *pull, culture, adult* and *multiple*. The dictionary says it should be /ʌ/. I heard a Canadian teacher pronounce "culture" /'kol tʃɘr/. My pronunciation is between /o/ and /ʌ/, so I think it's a mid back rounded vowel: /o̞/.

Am I the only American who pronounces "ul" like this? For your reference, as an ESL teacher, I generally speak General American, have mostly lived in Northern California, but also in western North Carolina for four years.

Comment: For me (GenAmE), 'pull doesn't sound the same as the other two. It's /pʊl/, like the oo in 'book'.

Comment: @Mitch: ditto for me. But the Merriam-Webster [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull) says *pull* (as well as *bull, full*, and probably any word with /ʊl/) can be pronounced either way.